# Having issues using js to randomly reassign a css variable

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a part of a page that should load a random image from a folder every fraction of a second for a rapid shuffle. I've gotten it to get the file name and randomly set a style for it. Problem is, not at all how I was intending to do so. I want to set the css variable "--background-images" in my stylesheet, however all it seems to be doing upon manually running the function in console is adjust the html doc like so:

```
<html lang="en" style="--background-images\::url(\.\.\/\.\.\/rsrc\/acct-crt-page-images\/acct-crt-street-mural-16\.png);"><head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Create Account - Page 37</title>
    <script src="../scripts/script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/account-creation-style.css" type="text/css">
</head>
```

Obviously this isn't what I was aiming to change--and beyond that I have no idea what that url it inserted is as it looks like a nightmare. I'm aiming to replace only the line in the css file. This is my js code:

```
// Load the root CSS variables
const style_root = document.querySelector(':root')

function random_image() {
  // Get a random index postion of the images array
  array_index = Math.floor(Math.random() * 19)++;

  // Change the --background-images css variable based on the random index
  style_root.style.setProperty(`--background-images`, `url(../../rsrc/acct-crt-page-images/acct-crt-street-mural-${array_index}.png)`);
}
```

I don't really know where to start or what is happening here now--I've been working with this aspect of the website for almost a week, and I was getting close but this roadblock has had me for 2-3 days.

I'm attempting to change a line of css, but instead I've gotten a weird and confusing line that doesn't function in html.

Comment: Why do you have all those backslashes in the style?

Comment: You can't select pseudo-elements like `:root` with `querySelector()`.

Comment: To change the value of a CSS variable in `:root` you should look at something like `document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--myCssAtt', value);`

Comment: @Barmar What I was showing was what was actually happening when I run the code. That line with the backslashes is what the code actually inserts, and in the wrong file and place